# Standard way to hash an RSA key?

Tags: encryption, hash, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

What's the algorithm for creating hash (sha-1 or MD5) of an RSA public key?  Is there a standard way to do this?  Hash just the modulus, string addition of both and then take a hash?  Is SHA-1 or MD5 usually used?

I want to use it to ensure that I got the right key (have the sender send a hash, and I calculate it myself), and log said hash so I always know which exact key I used when I encrypt the payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the OpenSSH source code, the way that a fingerprint is generated for RSA keys is to convert n and e from the public key to big-endian binary data, concatenate the data and then hash that data with the given hash function.

Portions of the OpenSSH source code follows.  The comments were added to clarify what is happening.

```
// from key_fingerprint_raw() in key.c
switch (k->type) {
case KEY_RSA1:
    // figure out how long n and e will be in binary form
    nlen = BN_num_bytes(k->rsa->n);
    elen = BN_num_bytes(k->rsa->e);
    len = nlen + elen;
    // allocate space for n and e and copy the binary data into blob
    blob = xmalloc(len);
    BN_bn2bin(k->rsa->n, blob);
    BN_bn2bin(k->rsa->e, blob + nlen);

...

// pick a digest to use
switch (dgst_type) {
case SSH_FP_MD5:
    md = EVP_md5();
    break;
case SSH_FP_SHA1:
    md = EVP_sha1();
    break;

...

// hash the data in blob (n and e)
EVP_DigestInit(&ctx, md);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, blob, len);
EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, retval, dgst_raw_length);
```

From the `BN_bn2bin` [manual page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html):

`BN_bn2bin(a, to)` converts the absolute value of `a` into *big-endian* form and stores it at `to`. `to` must point to `BN_num_bytes(a)` bytes of memory.

Comment: This method here to hash a key is not collision resistant. I.e. it is easy to find a different pair (n', e') e.g. by removing a byte from n and appending it to e, such that the resulting blob does not change. There is even a fair chance that an attacker can factor such a modulus n', for example if all but one prime factor of n' is small. 

If collision resistance is needed then for example the length of the two integers n and e should be encoded into the string that is hashed, e.g. by using a DER encoding of the string.

Comment: I don't want to claim here that SSH is doing something wrong here. I.e. it does not depend on the key hash being collision resistant. I also don't know if the OP needs a collision resistant hash, because the question is not specific enough to determine, whether an attacker who can find another key with the same key hash can exploit it. Rather it is genarally a bad idea to just pick some random code snippet and use it for something, that might have different requirements.